# Calculation in Java

Tags: java, int, double, divide

I have the following calculation in Java:

```
rightMotor = (int) (((double)speed)/((double)100)*rightMotor));
```

Speed and rightMotor are both integers.
The problem is, it keeps returning 0. I have tried to force to divide speed and 100 as doubles, which had no different results. Can anyone give me some insight in this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the values of `speed` and `rightMotoer`?

Comment: speed is between 1 and 100. rightMotor is 1024.

Comment: Exactly, if the result is between -0.5 and 0.5, casting it at int will result in 0.

Comment: Then the result is lower than 0.01 and the casting to int will approx it to 0. That's not what you wanted to do, I'm betting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the calculation returns zero is that the `double` value computed by the expression is less than one.

It looks like you have placed the parentheses incorrectly - currently, you divide `speed` by hundred times `rightMotor`, which is bound to produce a value less than `1`.

You need to fix your formula to make it work. If you wanted to compute `speed / 100 * rightMotor` as if it were a math formula, you could do the multiplication ahead of division, avoiding `double`s altogether:

```
rightMotor = speed * rightMotor / 100;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are assigning the result to an int variable, there's no point in doing floating point division.

```
rightMotor = speed/(100*rightMotor);
```

would give you the same result, which would be 0 if `speed < 100*rightMotor`.

If your intent was to multiply `speed/100` by `rightMotor`, you still don't need to cast to double and then back to int.

Just do:

```
rightMotor = (speed*rightMotor)/100;
```